# Is it possible to half-page down and up in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have been trying to scroll half-page down/up within Eclipse (in Windows). Checked key-bindings but found nothing there. Is this possible in Eclipse with a short cut key? If it is not possible then can I integrate this with a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self answering after a long time.

This is possible with **[Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/)** (Vim-like) plugin for Eclipse. It is basically bringing Vim environment in Eclipse but without breaking any existing Eclipse functionality.

Same shortcuts in Vim is valid also for this plugin.

`CTRL+D` is half-page down.
`CTRL+U` is half-page up.

Before using Vrapper keyboard shortcuts, make sure you unbind those keys from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, there is no defined function that will scroll up/down a half page.  I'm not aware of a plugin that provides this.  One plugin that provides several functions related to navigation (and many others) is Emacs+, but that also does not provide any "half-page" navigation options.